# How to handle network state and HTTP status codes correctly

Tags: java, android, http, http-status-codes

Within a method I'm sending GET and POST requests using the HttpURLConnection. As you can see in the example code, I'm catching most of the exceptions. But I wonder if this is the correct way and how I actually should handle sitations like "no network available" and bad status codes in the response from the server? I ask this because I want to inform the user about the various problems.

```
public static Bitmap getImage(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {

        URL newUrl = new URL(url);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) newUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(false);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/png");
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.connect();

        int total = conn.getContentLength();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        // ... read the image here!
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.disconnect();

        if (progress != null)
            progress.setProgress(1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you just need to show user message related to network errors like timeout, gateway timeout, no data found. So just catch the ResponseCode and show the description for that code.

Answer (score 0):

use this to check if network is available or not

```
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                //connection aailable
            }else{
//no connection
}
```

if connection availabe you can make http requests & if later any connection errors occur
then exception.getMessage() gives proper error message that can be displayed to user

Comment: This is just part of it. You also need to check on the HTTP status code or connection timeout.

Answer (score -1):

try below code and add as per your requirement in below class:-

```
catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress(ExceptionHandling.getFormattedMessageFromException(e.getMessage()));
        }
```

**ExceptionHandling.java**

```
public class ExceptionHandling
{
    public static String exception= "No address associated with hostname";
    public static String exceptionReturn = "No Internet Connection";
    public static String exceptionTimeOut = "ETIMEDOUT";
    public static String exceptionTimeoutReturn = "Connection time out, try again";
    public static String exceptionConnectionRefused = "Connection to http://54.254.213.212 refused";
    public static String exceptionConRefusedReturn = "Connection lost, please try again...";
    public static String exceptionEconnReset = "ECONNRESET";
    public static String exceptionSOCKET = "SocketTimeoutException";

    public static String exceptionTimeOuturl ="Connect to /154.25.13.12:80 timed out";
    public static String exceptionTimeOuturl1 ="ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/154.25.13.12:80  timed out";
    public static String exceptionTimeOuturlreturn2 ="time out";
    public static String exceptionTimeOuturlreturn3 ="refused";


    public static String exceptionTimeOuturlreturn ="Connection time out, try again";
    public static String exceptionEConnResetReturn = "Trying to connect ... ";

    public static String returnVal = "Server connection failed. Please try again.";

    public static String getFormattedMessageFromException(String exceptionMessage)
    {
        try
        {
//          return returnVal;exceptionSOCKET
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionSOCKET))
            {
                return exceptionTimeoutReturn;
            }
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exception))
            {
                return exceptionReturn;
            }
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionTimeOut))
            {
                return exceptionTimeoutReturn;
            }
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionConnectionRefused))
            {
                return exceptionConRefusedReturn;
            }
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionEconnReset))
            {
                return exceptionEConnResetReturn;
            }
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionTimeOuturl))
            {
                return exceptionTimeOuturlreturn;
            }
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionTimeOuturl1))
            {
                return exceptionTimeOuturlreturn;
            }
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionTimeOuturlreturn2))
            {
                return exceptionTimeOuturlreturn;
            }
            if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionTimeOuturlreturn3))
            {
                return exceptionConRefusedReturn;
            }
            else
            {
                return exceptionConRefusedReturn; 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return exceptionMessage;
    }

}
```

**add more messages.**

Comment: Good starting point. But most of your error cases can be found using [HttpStatusCode](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html) instead of doing string comparison, right?

Comment: A terrible starting point. An unholy mess that relies on undocumented properties of the various exceptions' messages and ignores the correct way to do it, which is to *catch* them, separately.